# Automatically lcd to ~/Downloads on every lftp connect

Tags: lftp

How can I configure lftp to automatically `lcd` to `~/Downloads` whenever I connect to any FTP server?

Comment: What is your operating system?

Answer (score 2):

Any commands in `~/.lftprc` are executed on lftp startup after /etc/lftp.conf (also see the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lftp)). If you create that file and put the line `lcd ~/Downloads` in it, it will do as you asked.

Comment: Can you expand on that a little?  like where and how?  "drop into" is pretty nebulous and may not be apparent to other people searching for a solution to this problem who find your answer through a search.